# NextJs React-Quill Dynamic import not working how can i solve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, quill, react-quill

I am using NextJs with React-Quill ı am getting error.

**Error : - error - unhandledRejection: ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object. \node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:7661:12)**

When I did research they said to use dynamic import for this problem. But dynamic also not working.

dynamic import not working, is there any other solution ?

I also Try _app js folder conditional render (typeof window !== "undefined") not work.

My Code Here >

```
import React from 'react';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const ReactQuill = dynamic(import('react-quill'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <p>Loading ...</p>,
});

function EditService() {
  return <ReactQuill />;
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession({ req: context.req });

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}

export default EditService;
```

Comment: I think your code is legit, I tested it in code sandbox and the `dynamic` import with `ssr: false` does the trick.
There might be a cache issue from HMR during your development.

Comment: There is no cache,ı cleared. Also, ı tried in production mode :/ not working

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stoic-yonath-g6ewh7?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A8%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A8%7D%5D  check the link, I actually try out the package in next.js, there might be something wrong with your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Try import like this:

```
const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import('react-quill'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <p>Loading ...</p>,
});
```